# Linq returning single integer value based on string stored in SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm quite new to Linq,

I'm just trying to do a routine return which is usually done in SQL and cannot seem to get a straight answer from viewing many forums with hours of browsing.

Ok, I have a table Customers with two columns, CustomerID and CustomerName which belong to a CustomersDataBase

I have successfully been able to return single string from an integer query using the following method (in its basic form):

```
public string getCustomerName(int custID)
{
    CustomerDataBase cdb = new CustomerDataBase();

    string custName = (
        from c in cdb.Customers
        where c.CustomerID == custID
        select c.CustomerName)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    return custName;
}
```

Ok that's fine but when I try to inverse the situation with trying to return the CustomerID it returns an Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

This is my code:

```
public int getCustomerID(string custName)
{
    CustomerDataBase cdb = new CustomerDataBase();

    int custID = (
        from c in cdb.Customers
        where c.CustomerName == custName
        select c.CustomerID)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    return custID;
}
```

I've also tried thinking SQL terms to make the custName string a char array:

```
public int getCustomerID(string custName)
{ 
    CustomerDataBase cdb = new CustomerDataBase();

    int custID = (
        from c in cdb.Customers
        where c.CustomerName == "'"+custName+"'"
        select c.CustomerID)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    return custID;
}
```

The exception disappears but only seem to be returning a "0" for the CustomerID even though I have hundreds of entries.

So in SQL I would just use the following:

```
Select CustomerID 
from   Customers 
where  CustomerName="'"+custName+"'"
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

//Edits to code to make it work (following answer from Jon Skeet):-

Ok This works:

[Table(Name = "TableCustomers")]
    public class Customers
    {

```
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public long CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    [Column]
```

}
//for accomadating for BigInt in SQL Database

public long getCustomerID(string custName)
        {

```
        CustomerDatabase cdb = new CustomerDatabase();



           long custID = (from c in cdb.Customers

                          where c.CustomerName == custName
                          select c.CustomerID).SingleOrDefault();

        return custID;
    }
}
```

Comment: The last query will return zero records, the OrDefault() part will return int 0. That's why you don't get a cast exception. What is the type of CustomerId in your code?

Comment: [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }   Customer ID is non-Nullable and BigInt in the SQL Database as well as Primary Key

Comment: Format I am using:      [Table(Name = "TableCustomers")]
    public class Customers
    {


        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }}

Comment: Code doesn't work well in comments. You're allowed to edit your question to add more information.

Answer (score 4):

Your final approach is *definitely* wrong - you don't need to manually "quote" parameters; basically you're searching for a value *with the quotes*, and it's returning `0` from `SingleOrDefault` because it hasn't found the entry. (That's what `SingleOrDefault` does - it returns the default value for the type (`int`, here) if there are no results.)

I *suspect* that your `CustomerID` column is nullable, or something like that - but it's hard to tell without knowing more about your schema. You should check whether your LINQ to SQL model matches your database schema.

You should *also* consider what you want to happen if there are multiple customers with the same name - currently this will throw an exception; is that what you want?

EDIT: Okay, now you've finally told us what the schema has, it's clear. `BigInt` is a 64-bit integer, but you're using a 32-bit property in the LINQ model. Simply change `CustomerID` from an `int` to `long` in your LINQ model, change your method to return a `long` as well, and it should all be fine.

Comment: CustomerID is not Nullable and is the primary key. For this example I have I am just using unique customer names (I have ways of handling this conflict but tried to simplify here to see how I can trial returning ids from strings). I will check the model again. though to check if there are any conflicts..Thanks

Comment: Also CustomerName is non Nullable

Comment: @amundell: And what's the *type* of CustomerID, exactly (in the database)? Is there any more information in the `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: Ok this is in an ASP.Net 3.5 Web Application:= following error[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +1143
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +115

Comment: So no more message, or an inner exception? And once again, what is the type of CustomerID in your database?

Comment: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +355
 System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +23
   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +211
   LinqDemo.TestingLinq.getCustomerID(String custName) in (Changed).cs:77 TestLinq.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in (Changed).cs:16System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14

Comment: System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +46
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +120
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3954

Comment: The type is a non-Nullable BigInt in SQL Database, also Primary Key

Comment: Sorry about the split posting of the exception

Comment: @amundell: Okay, finally, BigInt. That explains things. (This is why I asked about the schema right from the very start.) Will edit.

Comment: The CustomerName is varchar(50) if that helps

Comment: @amundell: No, that's irrelevant. See my edit - your schema type doesn't match your LINQ model type for `CustomerID`.

Comment: Success!! Your editing worked. Used Long So I will post my answer in full! Thanks for your help mate!

Comment: @amundell: Why would you need to post an answer? My answer already says what's required, doesn't it?